# Update query in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables   **table1** with fields **f1**, **f2**

and

**table2** with fields **id,f1,f2**, where id is incremental field

I need to take the values from  **table1** and need to insert into **table2**

Can anyone give the query for that,in sql server

Comment: Really need to accept more answers....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table2(f1,f2) SELECT f1,f2 FROM table1
```

That will do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table2
    (f1, f2)
    SELECT f1, f2
        FROM table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out `select into` or `insert into`

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/15/sql-server-insert-data-from-one-table-to-another-table-insert-into-select-select-into-table/